# passwordless check to see if a user can use 'sudo'

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, sudo, command-substitution

I want to check if a user is able to use `sudo` - but **without** the need to write the password - for bash shell scripts purposes. I did some research and I found:

- [Sudo - is there a command to check if I have sudo and/or how much time is left?](https://superuser.com/questions/195781/sudo-is-there-a-command-to-check-if-i-have-sudo-and-or-how-much-time-is-left)

For a user that does not have a configuration through in `sudoers` - therefore impossible to use `sudo` - the execution of `sudo -n <command>` **always** prints in the terminal the `sudo: a password is required` message. And if the user can use `sudo` --whether `sudo` was not executed in the session or the `sudo`'s *timeout* expired -- it prints again the `sudo: a password is required` message.

Additionally, with the correct solution (but for the other scenario)

```
$(sudo -n uptime 2>&1 | grep "load" | wc -l)
```

For an user without `sudo` permission **always** returns 0. And if the user can use `sudo` and if the `sudo`'s *timeout* is still valid - it returns 1, otherwise it returns 0

**Problem**: so with this approach is **not** possible really know through a command know if the user can use `sudo` - the solution is only viable to know if the `sudo`'s *timeout* is still valid or not.

- [How to check if I have sudo access?](https://superuser.com/questions/553932/how-to-check-if-i-have-sudo-access)

With `sudo -v` so far almost the solution happens the following:

For an user that does not have a configuration about `sudoers` the command returns

```
Sorry, user <username> may not run sudo on <hostname>.
```

If the user can use `sudo` then the `sudo -v` asks for the password.
If either it is valid or `sudo`'s *timeout* is still valid it returns *empty*. So until here there is a clear difference and the solution **but** because I am working with `Bash Shell` and I need use *Command Substitution*

```
is_user_sudo=$(sudo -v) # if is empty sudo can be used otherwise not
```

**Problem** I want avoid the password prompt part. That would be a solution.

Or if exists other parameter such as `sudo -k` that does not ask for the password (of course it does other thing) or other command to accomplish my goal.

**Goal**: only the *non-root* users - that can use `sudo` - can be able to execute some bash scripts. Therefore internally in the script I need the command to identify that type of *non-root* user - so the `non-root` users that can't not use `sudo` must be notified and stop the script execution.

For example:

```
# an if statement about 'id -u' not equals a 0
can_use_sudo=$(<command> whoami) # so the non-root user 
                                 # is able to use sudo or not?
```

`whoami` can be replaced by other command, that identifies **who** is running the script

Comment: Sudoers config can be very specific, allowing for some commands but not others.  Also it may allow running as only specific users.  Are you wanting to just answer "Is there *at least one* command this user can successfully run through sudo, as *some* user?" or are you wanting to verify unlimited root sudo access, or somewhere in between?

Comment: Both scenarios have sense. But mostly the latter.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain what the final objective is? Only root can know the details of what users are allowed to run what commands, anything else would be a huge security breach. Do you want to have _any_ user be able to check if _any_ other user can run _any_ command as _any_ user with sudo?

Comment: @terdon added the _goal_ section

Comment: So what you are actually asking is how can _this_ user know if they can run a _specific_ command? You don't need userA to be able to check if userB has access, each user only needs to check for themselves? And what doe s"use sudo" mean? Do you mean "use sudo to run a command as root" or "use sudo to run a command as some other user, not necessarily root"? And one last thing, your `sudo` user will have to enter a password to run the command, so why do you object to the password prompt?

Comment: See the example added pls. It should be generic.

Comment: You mean it should not be generic, it should be i) specific to the user running the script, you don't need that user to be able to check for other users and ii) specific to using `sudo` to execute _any_ command as the `root` user (`sudo` can be used to run commands as any user, not only root). Is that correct?

Comment: `i) specific to the user running the script, you don't need that user to be able to check for other users and` Yes, if the user is able to check other users is not included in my scenario - it is because I am going to use in the script `whoami` -

Comment: `ii) specific to using sudo to execute any command as the root user (sudo can be used to run commands as any user, not only root). Is that correct?` - It such as the primary user or first linux account created when Linux was installed - or perhaps if an user X through `sudoers` has granted `ALL`. Therefore as `root` user - `sudo <anycommand>`

Answer (score 11):

I admit that I don't quite understand why you would want this and why you don't just run `sudo whoami` or something at the beginning of the script to immediately ask users for a password and exit if they cannot continue, but no matter. This should work, at least on Linux systems (haven't checked other `sudo` implementations):

```bsh
sudo_response=$(SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami 2>&1 | wc -l)
if [ $sudo_response = 2 ]; then
    can_sudo=1
elif [ $sudo_response = 1 ]; then
    can_sudo=0
else
    echo "Unexpected sudo response: $sudo_response" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The trick here is to take advantage of the `askpass` option of `sudo` which tries to use another program to validate the password. By setting it to `/bin/false`, we can get two standard responses based on whether the user can run `sudo` commands as root or not:

```
## A user with sudo rights
terdon@tpad $ SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami 2>&1 
sudo: no password was provided
sudo: a password is required

## A user without sudo rights
bib@tpad $ SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami
bib is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Therefore, if the response after redirecting stderr to stdout is two lines, the user can run `sudo` commands and if it is one, the user cannot.

***Important***: I haven't tested this extensively, I have only tried two users as shown above on a single Arch Linux system. I wouldn't be surprised if this doesn't work as expected on other systems if the output of the command above can change.

For an obvious fail case: this will not work if the user is configured to run `sudo` commands without a password.

Comment: Your first sentence has sense and was evaluated from the beginning - but be asking the password each 5 minutes (default `sudo's timeout`) or many times throughout the day is annoying for some users. And of course, I created this post assuming that is possible do this without asking the password, something like `sudo -k` is able to do.

Comment: @ManuelJordan if you want to exit if the user cannot run sudo, then you just need _one_ password prompt, no need to check without prompting. You have two cases: 1) the user cannot run sudo commands, so the script exits at the first `sudo` or 2) the user can run `sudo` commands which means they will have to be prompted for   a password. So I don't understand why you would want something this complicated and unsafe. If you want to avoid prompting multiple times, that is a different question and is possible: usually this is done by running `sudo script.sh` instead of having sudo in the script.

Comment: If you want to check for passwordless users, after `can_sudo=0`, add an `if` to check if `$(SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami 2>&1)` equals to `root`, this will also make it work in the sudo timeout

Comment: There is a third option. If the user has configured their sudoers file with `NOPASSWD`, the sudo will succeed and "root" will be printed.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't found explicit confirmation, but I think that **by design** there is no way to do this without authentication or permissions.

I don't think an unprivileged user *should* be able to choose an arbitrary user and an arbitrary command and check if that user has permissions to run that command with `sudo`.  This would greatly aid any attacker in probing the system to learn which accounts would be most valuable to compromise, and it's unclear what benefit it would bring.

Notably, the `/etc/sudoers` file is locked down by default and not readable except to root.

Answer (score 1):

> I want check through a command if an user is able to use `sudo` - but **without** the need to write the password

`groups user_name` will show all groups a user is a member of. If the user is a member of the `sudo` group, then the user ***might*** be able to use `sudo` *(as @terdon points out group membership is not what grants permission to use `sudo`, but in the typical case where users are created simply as either "regular users" or "administrators", sudo group membership correlates with being able to use `sudo`)*.

```bsh
if [ -z "$(groups user_name | grep sudo)" ]; then
    echo 'user is not in sudo group'
else
    echo 'user is in sudo group'
fi
```

Of course this won't tell you about any finer-grained permissions that might be in the `sudoers` file - you need root to read that.

Comment: This could indeed work in some cases, but note that the `sudo` group is just a name used by some systems. There is no requirement that sudo users be in a group specifically called `sudo`, and in fact may systems use `wheel` instead. In any case,  a system could have whatever name the sysadmin has chosen, this is entirely configurable.

Comment: ... and that is completely configurable *per machine*.  It is not necessarily the case that there is *any* group that confers elevated privileges on members, even for OS distributions that ordinarily provide such a group.  Furthermore, where there is such a group, it is in no way guaranteed that non-members are without sudo privileges.  Also, exactly what privileges `sudo` provides is highly configurable, and not necessarily consistent across users and groups.

Comment: @terdon true. I was considering only the generic case where users are created as either "regular users" or "administrators" using preconfigured settings.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings even then, I am not at all sure that `sudo` is more common than `wheel` as the default sudoers group.

Comment: @terdon I suppose it depends a lot on which Linux distribution is being used.

Comment: Yes, or if the system is even Linux. The OP didn't specify, so they might be using any *nix system.