# Focus bash window when prompting for sudo

Tags: bash, debian, sudo

I have a script looping every five minutes in a bash window on my Debian machine. One of the commands in the loop is called with `sudo`. When I first start the script, I enter the `sudo` password, then for a few subsequent loops I don't have to do it.

After some time, `sudo` will prompt for my password again, effectively halting the script. I know that this time can be lengthened, but that's not what I want to do. I would like the bash window to come into focus when and only when it prompts for the password. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no ways to detect if the `sudo` command will open a password prompt beforehand, but you can circle that back by taking advantage of the `askpass` feature (see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/692109/407300) for the basis and explanation)

```
sudo_response=$(SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami 2>&1 | wc -l)
if [ $sudo_response = 2 ]; then
    # Password need to be inserted
    can_sudo=1
elif [ $sudo_response = 1 ]; then
    can_sudo=0
    # Check if currently in sudo timeout, which means no password to insert
    sudo_response=$(SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami 2>&1)
    # Check if `whoami` is equal to `root`      
    if [ sudo_response == "root" ]; then
        can_sudo=2
    fi
else
    echo "Unexpected sudo response: $sudo_response" >&2
    exit 1
fi
# can_sudo legend
## 0: Doesn't have sudo permission
## 1: Needs to insert password
## 2: No need to insert password
```

Then, check `can_sudo==1` and provided your terminal supports it, and it is enabled (how it will react depends on the terminal and the DE)

You can use the `BELL` ASCII character, by sending the following command :

```bash
echo -e "\a"
```

It should make the window flash or pop to top depending on DE

Comment: Nice trick! Your solution partially works but in an unexpected way. Now I have a sudo call at every iteration `sudo_response=$(SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami 2>&1 | wc -l)`. As the loop runs at an interval lower than the timeout value, it means a sudo timeout can never occur. So there is actually no need for the rest of the logic.

Comment: Concerning the `echo -e "\a"` part, it doesn't focus the windows but I managed to do it with a gdbus call : `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "var mw = global.get_window_actors().map(w=>w.meta_window).find(mw=>mw.get_title().includes('script-name')); mw.activate(0)"`.  The shell window title needs to be set with `printf '\033]2;script-name\a'`.