Check if current user can run sudo without requiring a password
I want to check if the current user running a BASH shell script has access to passwordless sudo or not.  If they don't, I'd rather have the script exit rather than prompting them for a password.

You might also investigate the option -n for batch mode.

I get the impression that you ask "How can I use elevated privileges if available, without giving away the attempt to use them if they are not?". Please clarify what I misunderstood, because that would have a worrying smell of malicious software.

I get your point, but the intent is only a convenience for my own local scripts.  It's trivial for an actively malicious actor to spawn a process which tests capabilities and reports back without the user receiving any visible indication that bad things are happening.

If all you want to check is whether the user has access to passwordless sudo, then you can simply run sudo -n. From man sudo:
       -n, --non-interactive
               Avoid prompting the user for input of any kind.   If  a
               password  is required for the command to run, sudo will
               display an error message and exit.


This means sudo -n will just return an error unless the user can run sudo without a password. The more complex example with SUDO_ASKPASS was to determine if the user had permission to run sudo at all, checking for passwordless sudo is simpler. You can just do something like:
if sudo -n true 2>/dev/null; then
  echo "user can run passwordless sudo" 
else
  echo "user cannot run passwordless sudo" 
fi

Or even
sudo -n true 2>/dev/null && 
  echo "user can run passwordless sudo" || 
    echo "user cannot run passwordless sudo" 

Or, in a script, if you just want to exit:
sudo -n true 2>/dev/null || exit 1

Of course, this only checks if the user can currently run sudo commands without a password. It doesn't distinguish between the case of a user who has already been authenticated and is within the sudo timeout so isn't prompted for a password and a user who has been given the right to run all commands without a password generally. I assume this is the desired behavior since nothing to the contrary was mentioned in the question and the OP's own answer works in the same way. If you only want to check for full passwordless sudo, you can just run a sudo -k to clear the current credentials beforehand:
$ sudo -k; sudo -n true 2>/dev/null && 
  echo "user can run passwordless sudo" || 
    echo "user cannot run passwordless sudo" 

Now, as @Kamil Maciorowski mentioned in the comments, this will fail in cases where the user might have been given passwordless sudo access to /usr/bin/true specifically. To guard against that, you could do something like this instead:
ln -sf /usr/bin/true /tmp/ && sudo -n /tmp/true 2>/dev/null &&   
    echo "user can run passwordless sudo" ||     
      echo "user cannot run passwordless sudo" 
rm /tmp/true

Here, by making a symlink /tmp/true that points to /usr/bin/true,  this will work even if /usr/bin/true is set to run with passwordless sudo. Now, if we're being paranoid, it is theoretically possible that someone has also set /tmp/true to run with passwordless sudo. To guard against that unlikely scenario as well, you could do:
rand=$(mktemp /tmp/true.XXXXX); cp /usr/bin/true "$rand" &&
  sudo -n "$rand" 2>/dev/null &&   
    echo "user can run passwordless sudo" ||     
      echo "user cannot run passwordless sudo" 
rm "$rand"

Here, we copy /usr/bin/true (which is a tiny 27K file on my system) to the /tmp dir with a random name (guaranteed to not exist) and then do the check with that. While it is still theoretically possible that someone might have randomly added that specific string to sudoers, the chances of that are so small I think it is safe to ignore them.

+1. Note that sudo also has a --validate flag (-v for short), which seems potentially more appropriate than running true.

Oh, but: under typical configurations, sudo doesn't require a password if the user has recently run sudo and provided a password. In that case sudo -n will pass, even though the user doesn't actually have access to passwordless sudo. For the use-case that the OP describes, that's probably desired behavior, but I mention it for the benefit of other readers who might want to check passwordless sudo access for a different reason.

I think it's not that simple. What if sudoers includes NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/true and no other NOPASSWD?

@ruakh yes, exactly. That's is the desired behavior: if the user can run sudo commands without a password, then they can run sudo commands without a password. The question didn't specify that this should not consider cases where the user has already been authenticated. And the OP's answer would also behave the same, so I assumed that's what is desired. I added a version that avoids that, for completeness.

@KamilMaciorowski that's a fair point, but the OP has specified that this is about users using bash and since bash has a true builtin, that will always be run before the executable in /usr/bin, so I think we're still safe. We wouldn't for a shell without a true builtin though, you're quite right.

Well, I think sudo -n true runs the external true anyway. My point is NOPASSWD: /the/right/path/to/the/external/true will make your test always succeed, even if sudo anything_else does require a password.

@KamilMaciorowski While true, it seems like the only reason for such a configuration would be to confound scripts like this. Since sudoers is presumably edited by reliable admins, do we really need to protect against that?

@Barmar It may be the other way around. It may be NOPASSWD: /path/to/the/actual/command/the/OP/wants. The more general point is sudo -n something cannot really tell you if sudo smthng_else needs a password.

Dammit, @KamilMaciorowski, of course it runs the external one, you're absolutely right. The update should fix that, thanks.

@terdon But it doesn't. builtin is a builtin and sudo builtin … will not run it because it does not run a shell in the first place. sudo -s … or sudo bash -c … runs a shell; I'm not sure if these can help in general though, my reason is in my previous comment.

@KamilMaciorowski sigh, yep. I was redirecting stderr and missed it. OK, for what I hope is the last time, check out the updated answer. This should work.

Fundamentally, it's not possible to generalise a check "if the current user [..] has access to passwordless sudo". For various reasons (it's a test system) I can sudo id without a password from/to any user. But sudo ls requires a password (subject to sudo -k and timeouts). The only way to test if someone can run command x as root is to test with sudo -n x – and understand that the result does not also automatically apply to command y

@ChrisDavies can you think of a way my last attempt here could fail to be conclusive other than the almost impossible case where that specific random string has been explicitly allowed in sudoers?

Yes. Where you have certain commands that don't require a password for execution but where the majority do. Your test will fail on the majority branch despite the command(s) intended for real use being permitted by the special case(s) in sudoers

@ChrisDavies how? I am testing using a random name. Unless that specific random string has been added to sudoers, how can I fail to be on the majority branch? [edit] Oh right, you mean that there won't be one single answer. Yes, OK, sure, but I am thinking of the general case here, there is no way to deal with all the specifics.

I've tested this in BASH across a few major Linux distributions like Debian, Redhat, and Oracle Enterprise Linux 7.  This technique doesn't work under FreeBSD or any BSD (including macOS).
if SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A true 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo 'Current user has access to passwordless sudo'
else
    echo 'Current user DOES NOT have access to passwordless sudo'
fi

This leverages the askpass option of sudo which tries to use another program to validate the password.  By setting it to /bin/false, one of two standard responses is returned based on whether the user can run passwordless sudo commands or not.
Test cases
The test case matrix is as follows:
Case 1. User with passwordless sudo rights
terd1@host $ SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A true 1>/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
0

Case 2. User with sudo rights but requiring a password
terd2@host $ SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A true 1>/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
1

Case 3. A user without any sudo rights
terd3@host $ SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A true 1>/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?
1

If the return code is 0, the user can run passwordless sudo commands, if it is non-zero (e.g. 1), said user doesn't have access.
p.s. Thanks to terdon for providing a starting point for this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/692109/22709

For you use case, you can probably use true instead of whoami 1>/dev/null 2>&1.

Also, in bash the then clause is executed if the if clause returns 0. So you should not have ! in your first code block. (AKA "bash is not C".)

@TomYan Thanks for your corrections and improvements - enthusiastically incorporated :)

Note that this logs a failed login attempt to the audit logs if the user has no sudo right (pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed), do not call this command multiple times if account lockout is enabled as you will be locked out of your system (be careful for this when testing your script that uses this)
